# Spaces with list environments in beamer class

Tags: beamer, spacing, lists, itemize

In some slides I am writing with the [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer) class, I want to eliminate the additional horizontal and vertical spaces that appears in list environments like `itemize` and `enumerate`, so that the environment does not look strange when used in a `tabular` environment. See the example below.

```
\documentclass[smaller]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame test}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|p{4cm}|}\hline
    Foo & This is a test.\\\hline
    Bar & \begin{itemize}
            \item First item.
            \item Second item.
          \end{itemize}\\\hline
    Baz & Last test.\\\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo of undesired spaces with enumerate]

In this sample document, I want the bullets vertically aligned with the entries of the second column in the first and third lines. Also I want no extra spaces before and after the list, and between the items in the list.

I already know that the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem) package and the [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer) class are not compatible, therefore it is not an option.

Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

Use a nested `tabular` with some [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) finesse:

[image]

```
\documentclass[smaller]{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\let\Tiny\tiny
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\newcommand{\itemizeitem}{%
  \usebeamerfont{itemize item}%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}%
  \usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}
\newenvironment{tabitemize}[1]
  {\renewcommand{\item}{&}% Fake \item
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{\itemizeitem}l@{\hspace{\labelsep}}#1@{}}}
  {\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame test}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}\hline
    Foo & This is a test. \\
    \hline
    Bar & \begin{tabitemize}{p{4cm}}
            \item First item. \\
            \item Second item.
          \end{tabitemize} \\
    \hline
    Baz & Last test. \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The environment `tabitemize` provides a faked `itemize` in a very similar interface. The first column (hidden as an `\item`) merely inserts the traditional `\item` content using the `beamer` template. The mandatory argument specifies the width of the itemized content using a `tabular`-style column specification.